# I cannot install tar.gz packages

Tags: python, installation, package, kaggle

When i was trying to install kaggle api (pip install kaggle), it showed an error message:

complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\harry\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a2tpgb17\kaggle\

I tried downloading the tar.gz file and using pip to install it and got the same error message.

Then I tried to use python setup.py install and the process did seem to be finished. But then when I checked the kaggle package, it still didn't exist.

Then I tried to install ez_setup as it is also a tar.gz file and it also didn't work.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip install --user kaggle` and read [this](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api)

And make sure you using python

Offical docs says: We do not offer **Python 2 support**. Please ensure that you are using **Python 3** before reporting any issues.